# How do I make my dice roll 1-6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've created a simple dice roller that works but I can't find a way to make it count out zero. I only want it to go 1-6. I'm using Action script 3.0. Here's what I have:

```
roll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rollDice);
function rollDice(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var die1:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var die2:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var diceTotal:uint = die1 + die2;

    die1_txt.text = die1.toString();
    die2_txt.text = die2.toString();
    status_txt.text = "You rolled "+diceTotal;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Since you know how to make a value between 0 and n, don't let n be 6. Instead, create a number between 0 and 5, and add one to it.

Comment: Correct comment. It's simple math really, max value possible: 6, min value possible: 1. so formula is min value + random() * (max value - min value)

Answer (score 0):

Just add +1 at the end of your random generator code, since random starts at 0.

```
var die1:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var die2:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```